# Node.js https.request() Error: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, https, xmlhttprequest

I'm using plain node.js script to make a POST request and the link that I make request to takes around 1 to 1.2 mins to respond and in that time I get this error `Error: socket hang up`.

I get the socket hang up error around the same time as I would have gotten the response from the server which is around 1 to 1.2 mins

I've tried setting connection: "keep-alive" in headers and setting timeout to 200000ms in options but no luck. Any help?

BTW the request works fine if i use axios

**Here's my script**

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const https = require("https")

const file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "data.csv"))

const options = {
  hostname: "example.com",
  path: "/example",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    <<headers>>
  }
  <<some other options>>
}

const req = https.request(options, response => {
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      console.log("started...")
      chunk.pipe(file)
    })
    response.on("end", function () {
      file.on("finish", function () {
        file.close()
      })
    })
  })

req.on("error", e => {
  console.error(e)
})
req.end()
```

**This is the full error:**

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:612:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:493:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1308:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Comment: Which is the url target?

Comment: @GermanFaller it's https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb_query.cgi

Comment: I dont have node right now, have you tried with postman? Try adding userAgent header, some sites checks those hesders to avoid bots.

Comment: @GermanFaller the thing is that my code is working fine with same options if i'm using axios but i wanted to do this without any external library

Comment: Does this work for other urls or is it only problematic for example. Com?

Comment: @bluejayke it works for other urls, maybe i'm getting this error because the response is too large around 500Mb? idk

Comment: If it's a large response then there are ways of processing it in chunks, it appears you are adding the chunks to a string, maybe concatting it to a buffer would be better and make sure your not application is configured to hold that much in runtime memory

Comment: @bluejayke i've edited my code above to write the chunks to a file but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the request after the first data chunk is through for testing

Comment: @bluejayke how do i do that? cancel the request

Comment: I think you can call `req.abort()`

Comment: Or maybe just do a partial request by setting a range header, then it it's successful name a new one with a shifted range

Comment: still the same error, plus i don't think req would be available inside callback of response.on(data)

Comment: Now I have node. I had to use `file.write(chunk)` instead of `chunk.pipe(...)` but also without content-length the server responds. Can you provide us the axios call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake i was making

**First** instead of doing `chunk.pipe(file)` inside `response.on('data')`
i directly did `response.pipe(file)` and it worked i don't know why exactly, i'm guessing it's because response is the stream and chunk is just the buffer, if anybody knows then please tell me.

**Second** i was setting the request body inside options, i had to set the request body parameter like this `req.write(formData)` where formData is a string that i want to send as request body.